# Assertions require every name in the call target to be declared with an explicit type annotation

Tags: typescript

Create a TS [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) named `assertIsQuerySignOrderStatusRequestDTO`.

```
export interface QuerySignOrderStatusRequestDTO {
  envSource: string;
  orderNo: string;
}

export function assertIsQuerySignOrderStatusRequestDTO(
  dto: any
): asserts dto is QuerySignOrderStatusRequestDTO {
  if (!dto?.orderNo) throw new Error('require parameter:orderNo');
  if (!dto?.envSource) throw new Error('require parameter:envSource');
}

export function querySignOrderStatus(dto: QuerySignOrderStatusRequestDTO) { }

const services = {
  assertIsQuerySignOrderStatusRequestDTO,
  querySignOrderStatus
}


function main() {
  try {
    const reqDTO = {};
    // doesn't work
    services.assertIsQuerySignOrderStatusRequestDTO(reqDTO);
    // works
    // assertIsQuerySignOrderStatusRequestDTO(reqDTO);
    services.querySignOrderStatus(reqDTO)
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
}
```

The assertion function throws a TS error when I try to call it via a namespace named `services`:

> Assertions require every name in the call target to be declared with an explicit type annotation.(2775)

> input.tsx(15, 7): 'services' needs an explicit type annotation.

It works fine when I call it directly(without a namespace). Why is it like this?

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.4#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgRQFc0BPAZQQHMkB5KAEzTJkxkIGcAlYAR2PZgARACo04AbwBQcOMCQA3MhEJRcALjgCoySgG5pcaIygA5CBq079AX0mTQkWHHSEk2GAghI4mduzQwAJLsRKQU1HTGzKwc3HzAAiI0ABQG9DDmPkgkkgCUGr7+sOxw6RCIJaFQ5FS0DEwsbFy8-EKiEgYI6HDJAIRlAPwAdEZoZrlwMAAWUBAA7nBIwAsAolCzUMkA5FAtCLtwYJhQmAC2wKhQaqOmEFu5+jJdPf0Zw3KKyqrAE9OzC0tVutoNtdnx9ngjidzpc1B8lCpcPcbHYHNB4C43B4vHB4tVwnUoo0OMkyhoqjUIvUoNEmnFWkkJuI4LZJNgvAJNGh5AhcCUALwdGSFALBCkEyINGLNeKJUQAGgMeMphKlTUkrMkmPcnm8p0wyGSTIMMGqQpkcHZSE5YKScEF4msjwtAHoXaUIAkkFt4HNoABrAwyIo8vlDEWwMXEfG1SU04kyhmiZK20QPINwN1wP1Qf3sDNZiNBELRlVx2mxFoJNopVM0dMWrlQUMJIbKiXUivsFO8RkGayW1jYKY9NBQY2Nq3sCAAG2AQzHILHuX7GqAA)

Answer (score 1):

Per [#33622](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/33622) this as designed. Types have to be explicit for the assertion to work. Here the type of `services` is only inferred.

The following definition fixes this :

```
const services: { assertIsQuerySignOrderStatusRequestDTO: typeof assertIsQuerySignOrderStatusRequestDTO, querySignOrderStatus: typeof querySignOrderStatus } = {
  assertIsQuerySignOrderStatusRequestDTO,
  querySignOrderStatus
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.4#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgRQFc0BPAZQQHMkB5KAEzTJkxkIGcAlYAR2PZgARACo04AbwBQcOMCQA3MhEJRcALjgCoySgG5pcaIygA5CBq079AX0mTQkWHHSEk2GAghI4mduzQwAJLsRKQU1HTGzKwc3HzAAiI0ABQG9DDmPkgkkgCUGr7%20sOxw6RCIJaFQ5FS0DEwsbFy8-EKiEgYI6HDJAIRlAPwAdEZoZrlwMAAWUBAA7nBIwAsAolCzUMkA5FAtCLtwYJhQmAC2wKhQaqOmEFu5%20jJdPf0Zw3KKyqrAE9OzC0tVutoNtdnx9ngjidzpc1B8lCpcPcbHYHNB4C43B4vHB4tVwnUoo0OMkyhoqjUIvUoNEmnFWkkJuI4LZJNgvAJNGh5AhcOwNMzCgFghSCZEGjFmvFEqINDASGBgBBukLYCLiPjauKacSpQzRAAaXEaymEiVNOUKpXdPGm7W0jgsuAAXg6MlVQRCJrF1IdeoSbRoBoMtp9RMlklZkkx7k83lOmGQySZBhg1TdMjg7KQnLBSRdEmsj0zAHoS6UIAkkFt4HNoABrAwyIo8vlDD3qsJa326%20kBpLJPOiB5NuBluB1qD19ij8cdr1dqnhuktfuiQe8RnF5vc3kJIah7vLklDmi5AzWLOsbBTHpoKApzNZjkQAA2wCG95B9-PMls1iAA)

Comment: Thanks. Is there a more convenient way to add an explicit type annotation to `services` instead of using `typeof` one by one? In fact, there are many methods in the `services` namespace.